# Knockout Native binding, Syntax error with containerless bindings

Tags: knockout.js

Working on my first serious native binding template and am making what will be an obvious syntax error.  The problem part is below -

```
<tr class="knockoutGrid-header">
    <!-- ko foreach: columns -->
    <th class="ui-widget-header">
        <!-- ko if:  !$data.NoSort  -->
        <button onclick='viewModel.gridViewModel.SortColumn("$data.rowText", $index)' class='GridSortWrapper'
            title='Click to Sort Column'>
            <div style="display: table">
                <div style="display: table-row">
                    <div class="ClearFix">
                    </div>
                    <div style="display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle; width: 100%;">
                        <label data-bind="text: headerText" />
                    </div>
                    <div style="display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle; width: 18px">
                        <span class='ui-icon $data.iconCss  iconBackground sortIcon'></span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="ClearFix">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </button>
        <!-- /ko -->
        <!-- ko if:  $data.NoSort   -->
        <label data-bind="text: headerText" />
        <!-- /ko -->
    </th>
    <!-- /ko -->
</tr>
```

I'm getting the following error

**Uncaught Error: Cannot find closing comment tag to match:  ko if:  $data.NoSort**

I'm using knockout 2.1RC

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like your problem is here: `<label data-bind="text: headerText" />`

It should be:  `<label data-bind="text: headerText"></label>`